# Can't use <gcc>(compile) on files in network drive

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

I have a network folder(Windows 10 / NTFS) in my Linux Mint Machine which i have my source codes i need to compile. Now i don't want to transfer them into my Linux File System but i want to compile them right there. I am accessing the network drive through `smb`.

The error i am getting is the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Operation not supported
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks for any kind of help!

I think its worth mentioning that the network drive is a network between a host(LinuxMint) and a guest (Win10) via Oracle Virtual Box.

EDIT:
running mount i can see the following line:
`gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)`. Which /run/user/1000/gvfs/ is the parent root of my network's folder `pwd` . Network path is like that `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.5xx.xxx,share=users/HomeUserX/test.c $`

Comment: Is the fs mounted with noexec?

Comment: I mounted the partition through Nemo's option 'connect to server' . 'mount' command doesn't list it sadly. Actually i found something in mount...i have editing my original post.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any updated solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue after connecting it using ssh from a terminal.  The same happened to me on Win10 / linux virtual box since I opened a local terminal after using the Connect to Server button instead.